# react-d3-tree boarder / centering

Tags: d3.js

I am using react-d3-tree. My problem is that the tree can be moved out of the user's field of view, so that it is no longer visible to the user and has to be searched for again.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-tree#styling-links

https://bkrem.github.io/react-d3-tree/

Is it possible to trigger the centering function by an "external" button instead of clicking on a node?

alternative would be to define a boarder so that the tree can only be moved around in a defined area?
Has anyone done this before?

i can't find any help in the api documentation for either approach.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I wrap my `<tree>` element in a div and adjust CSS as follows:

```css
.tree-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Now my tree stays in same place in screen

Comment: Its not working